# Combine several XML file to one XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have bunch of XML's and i want to produced 1 XML(in the same format) from all of them.

This is an example of 1.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootDTO xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
   <destination>
      <name>xxx</name>
   </destination>
   <orderData>                                         
      <items json:Array='true'>  
            <shipmentIndex Name="items"></shipmentIndex>
            <barcode>12345</barcode>                                                                                                       
      </items>  
      <misCode>9876543210</misCode>                                      
          <shipments>                                      
                <sourceShipmentId></sourceShipmentId>      
                <shipmentIndex Name="shipments"></shipmentIndex>                         
          </shipments>                         
   </orderData>
</RootDTO>
```

This one represent the Result.xml after combining `1.xml` and `2.xml`-(looks exactly the same like 1.xml

```
<!-- Represent Result.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootDTO xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
   <destination>
      <name>xxx</name>
   </destination>
   <orderData>                                         
      <items json:Array='true'>  
            <shipmentIndex Name="items"></shipmentIndex>
            <barcode>12345</barcode>                                                                                                       
      </items>  

    <items json:Array='true'>     <!-- from 2.xml-->
            <shipmentIndex Name="items"></shipmentIndex>
            <barcode>12345</barcode>                                                                                                       
      </items>  


      <misCode>9876543210</misCode>                                      
          <shipments>                                      
                <sourceShipmentId></sourceShipmentId>      
                <shipmentIndex Name="shipments"></shipmentIndex>                         
          </shipments>     


      <shipments>       <!--From 2.xml-->                              
                <sourceShipmentId></sourceShipmentId>      
                <shipmentIndex Name="shipments"></shipmentIndex>                         
          </shipments>                             
   </orderData>
</RootDTO>
```

The purpose of this is to combine several shipments(together, they are 1 order)  into 1 XML that represent full order.

Something like this pseudo:

```
for(i=0; i< xmls.count()< i++)
{
   itemsElement.appendTo(xml[i].items);
   shipmentsElement.appendTo(xml[i].shipments);
}
```

What i want to achieve is appending the elements - "**items**" and "**shipments**"
into 1 XML that will represent an order.

I am using this code to have my XML strng: `var xml = XElement.Parse(renderedOutput);` represent my XML string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplifiy sample code I added the same xml three times to the same document.  You can use the Load method instead of Parse to get xml from a file instead of a string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int NUMBER_OF_XML = 3;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                     "<RootDTO xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>" +
                       "<destination>" +
                          "<name>xxx</name>" +
                       "</destination>" +
                       "<orderData>" +
                          "<items json:Array='true'>" +
                                "<shipmentIndex Name=\"items\"></shipmentIndex>" +
                                "<barcode>12345</barcode>" +
                          "</items>" +
                          "<misCode>9876543210</misCode>" +
                              "<shipments>" +
                                    "<sourceShipmentId></sourceShipmentId>" +
                                    "<shipmentIndex Name=\"shipments\"></shipmentIndex>" +
                              "</shipments>" +
                       "</orderData>" +
                      "</RootDTO>";

            XDocument doc = null;
            XDocument addedDocs = null;
            for (int count = 0; count < NUMBER_OF_XML; count++)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedDocs = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                    XElement orderData = doc.Descendants("orderData").FirstOrDefault();
                    XElement addedOrderData = doc.Descendants("orderData").FirstOrDefault();
                    List<XElement> children = addedOrderData.Elements().ToList();
                    foreach (XElement element in children)
                    {
                        string tagName = element.Name.LocalName;
                        XElement lastElement = orderData.Elements(tagName).LastOrDefault();
                        if (lastElement == null)
                        {
                            orderData.Add(element);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastElement.ReplaceWith(new XElement[] { lastElement, element});
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i click "Run code snippet" nothing is shown. do you know why?

Comment: the language c# isn't specified.  Code will run in c#, it been tested.  Output is put in the doc document.

Comment: i have asked for a solution that will append each items after items and shipments to shipments, take a look at `result.xml` from my question.
Can you please fix it?

Comment: XML Order doesn't make a difference.  I changed the code to add items in order even though it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: For me it does.. i serialize it to JSON and send it to an API that's  accept only one structure.

Comment: You solution works fine, except- the tag `<misCode>` is loaded each time to the result -> is it possible to remove duplicates elements and leave only one?

Comment: Just test the variable tagName == "misCode" and skip the add/replace when it occurs.